# Perform database tasks in service

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-service

I am going to develop an application that should have service to run even though UI is not present. So I was thinking that should I do every database task in service or UI and service should perform them together?

I know it is possible to use database so that UI and service both can use, but I want to know which one is appropriate and has lower CPU usage. Which one is better: a shared database between UI and service or passing data from UI to service to perform all tasks in service?

Comment: Both solutions are OK, this is mainly personal taste/choice.

Comment: @m0skit0 ok, tell me pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing to be kept in mind for performance is to make potentially expensive database calls from the background thread. Simply calling it from a Service does not mean that it will be performed in the background. You can do your database calls from the UI as well but delegate them to an AsyncTask or some other background thread.

Querying the DB from a service depends on whether you want this action to happen over a period of time. If it should happen long after the user has exited your app, then yes - you should use a Service.

If by CPU usage, you mean that you want to conserve battery power over a period of time when DB calls are being made in the background at intervals of time, I'd suggest you look into the JobScheduler or AlarmManager.

Comment: Actually I was telling about performance. If I should insert something into db, I would call it right from activity but if I decided to do every db-job in service, I should pack data and pass it to service, then service insert it to db. Actually I will not have heavy db queries and I think most of my calls will be kind of should-wait-to-finish. So it will not bother user. I just wanted to know which architecture should I pick and which one is more effective. Thanks @Gogeta

Comment: It is highly recommended that you do not do any DB query from the main thread (calling it from the Activity). As @Gogeta said, you should do all your work in something like AsyncTask and when it is done, let your service/activity know that it is done. As for *where* you should perform the work from, that is up to how you design your app.

Comment: If your calls are wait-to-finish type, then I suggest you look into using the Loader framework - designed to query DBs specifically in such kind of scenarios. Since it looks like you are doing the work while the app is being actively used, for code simplicity, you should stick to running the query on either a background thread you create and start from your activity or simply implement the Loader framework.

Comment: @Gogeta BTW, what did you mean with if I want to conserve battery power, I should check JobScheduler?

Comment: A JobScheduler (or the somewhat similar AlarmManager) services are used to trigger jobs at some point in the future. If you do not want the device to wake up to complete your job (and thereby save battery power), you can batch jobs such that they will execute only when the device wakes up (for other purposes). The reasoning is since anyway you do not care about what the phone does when it's sleeping, why bother to wake up the device when the user is not interested